# Android Studio won't build my application

Tags: build, gradle, android-studio

Following the latest update of Android Studio, I did not import the settings (I didn't see the popup asking for it). So, it reset all my settings. (see http://tools.android.com/recent )
I thought this wasn't a big deal since I didn't personalize anything, and thought everything would work out.

But unfortunately, it didn't. It seems like it has broken the building process of my project. When I try from android studio to build, I got this error

`org.gradle.tooling.UnsupportedVersionException: The specified Gradle installation 'E:\Android Studio\plugins\gradle' is not supported by this tooling API version (1.7, protocol version 4): The specified Gradle installation 'E:\Android Studio\plugins\gradle' is not supported by this tooling API version (1.7, protocol version 4)`

I guess this is because something has changed in my AndroidStudio settings, because I'm still able to build using `gradlew build` in a terminal.

Do you have any idea of what I could do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved by deleting

`<option name="gradleHome" value="$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/plugins/gradle" />`

from my project's `.idea/gradle.xml`.

I won't be able to explain why, but I think it is because having a gradleHome in your .idea/gradle.xml makes AndroidStudio use this gradle instead of the gradle wrapper.